# Java - Thread-safe hash collection with no duplicates that is recoverable after crash

Tags: java, hashmap, thread-safety

I am new to java, and I'm developing an application that needs to do the following.  I need to read a high volume of files on multiple threads and perform a series of tasks on each file.  I cannot process duplicate files, and I need to know when I've attempted a duplicate file so that I can rename/move the file from our watch folder and send notification of such an attempt. Additionally, any number of these tasks to be performed could result in the file being aborted, so to speak, where we can we can make another attempt after changes to the file have been made. This also needs to be recoverable in the event of a crash so that no file is missed or mishandled.  These tasks to be performed could take a few milliseconds up to multiple seconds or possibly even minutes to complete.

My application is currently using multiple ExecutorServices and PriorityBlockingQueues for each task to be performed with an in-memory HashMap to keep track of which files we've already seen and to prevent duplicates.  At present, with each new file, I check if HashSet.add() is true/false. If false,  I rename the duplicate. For each file that is added to the HashSet, I add it to the first task's queue where multiple threads churn away on that queue and then either abort the file or pass to the next tasks's queue where multiple threads churn away and so on.

My thought was that I would continue down this road but with the following changes.  1.) The HashSet will be loaded from disk at startup and then workflow will proceed as I've outlined above. 2.) Once all tasks are completed then I'll write any file that isn't aborted to the HashSet on disk and it will remain in the in-memory hash map as well.

There will be multiple threads that addto the HashSet on disk and multiple threads that add to the HashSet in memory. As I stated, at times we'll want to reattempt a file that was previously aborted, and for this step it is possible that we'll require a change to one of the file's properties that our contains is evaluating...so it's not necessarily necessary that we have the ability to remove from the HashSet for files that we've aborted. We may require that we're presented with what we perceive as a new file for these scenarios.

All that said, I'm not looking for anyone to write or review my code so I won't post it here. Can I have multiple threads call HashSet.add() with no repercussions?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Despite your efforts to describe the situation, you are not really asking a question. Giving general advice is not really what StackOverflow’s Q&A format is good at.

Comment: No collection is appropriate, you need something persistent. Like a database.

Comment: Boris, I would most likely move the hash collection on disk to a database in the future.  I just thought I could get away with a thread safe collection on disk in the meantime and I didn't really want to hit a DB for my up front check if I could avoid it.

Comment: What are those tasks? What happens when your application crashes when task is being performed? Should it be retried from scratch?

Comment: Writing a thread safe, crash safe, multithreaded, indexed collection to disk is **highly** non-trivial. You are basically asking for advice on how to write an ACID compliant KV store. My conjecture is that if you are asking here then this is probably several orders of magnitude beyond your abilities and resources. Use a database.

Comment: I'm asking this...can I have multiple threads that are calling hashSet.add(obj) with no repercussions?  I won't be modifying any objects in the hashSet...only adding to and occasionally removing from the hashSet. If the answer is no, then what would be the appropriate collection to use?

Comment: No, you cannot - `HashSet` is not thread safe and using it in a threaded context without synchronization will result in Undefined Behaviour. It might work (unlikely), might produce random results - missing items, duplicate items, random exceptions (likely) or the universe might cease to exist (unlikely, but possible). You can of course syncrhonize, or use `Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<>())` (much better), but that doesn't solve the transactional nature of your problem - how do you ensure that the correct state is in the `Map` in case of errors or crashes...

Comment: ...what happens when then program crashes writing to disk? What happens when you write to the `Set` that work is done but it later fails? What happens if the application crashes after writing to the `Set` that work is done (preemtive locking) but then the processing fails and the application crashes before you can remove the item. Unless you have a transaction mechanism on your persistent store you have no guarantee that your data is consistent with state. This is what a database provides. I really don't think you'll achieve anything productive trying to implement something yourself.

Comment: Ok, Boris, you've convinced me to go the DB route.  How do I shoehorn the transaction into my workflow?  When a file is discovered, create a transaction and add the file entry to the DB?  Then add the transaction to the object that is added to the task queues?  Each task/queue performs its work. Then the last task/queue commits the transaction?  Thanks in advance.